# How To Convert PHP date into ISO 8601 format?

Tags: php, date, iso8601

I want a function in php that will return a date in following format

> 2017-01-25T08:55:40.000Z

I tried following

```
$obj->format(DateTime::ATOM); // output-> 2017-01-25T00:00:00+0100
$obj->format(DateTime::ISO8601); // output-> 2017-01-25T00:00:00+0100
```

I am not getting any solution for this in PHP - I am able to get this format in javascript using moment.js but not in PHP.

Comment: What class is your `$obj`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code::

```
echo date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime('2017-01-25 14:40:46'));
```